# EF6: How create a predicate which checks if a property is contained in the property of a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following case:
I have a function which I have to call:

```
class WorkobjectRepository...
public async Task<IList<WorkobjectView>> FindAllMatchingAsync(Expression<Func<WorkobjectView, bool>> whereExpression)
{
    return await this.WorkobjectContext.WorkobjectViews.AsNoTracking().Where(whereExpression).ToListAsync();
}
```

The Class `WorkobjectView` has among other properties the following two properties:

```
1. StatusDetailedDisplayName
2. AssignedSubteamId
```

Now I want all `WorkobjectView`s where `StatusDetailedDisplayName == StatusDetailedDisplay.activeOpen` and `AssignedSubteamId` is contained in a list of objects `UserAccountSubteam` where `UserAccountSubteam` has the property `Id`.

The following code works successfully for me:

```
// List<UserAccountSubteam> caredTeams, which is given
String[] teams = new string[caredTeams.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < caredTeams.Count; i++)
{
    teams[i] = caredTeams[i].Id;
}
return await this.WorkobjectRepository.FindAllMatchingAsync(w => w.StatusDetailedDisplayName == StatusDetailedDisplay.activeOpen && teams.Contains(w.AssignedSubteamId));
```

Now, I wanted to optimize the code using `LINQ` or using collection functions.
**Option 1:** The first one was using `LINQ` and `Exists` method:

```
var results =  await this.WorkobjectRepository.FindAllMatchingAsync(w => w.StatusDetailedDisplayName == StatusDetailedDisplay.activeOpen && caredTeams.Exists(team => team.Id == w.AssignedSubteamId));
```

But this failed and I received the following error message:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[Backend.DomainLayer.UserAccountSubteam])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

**Option 2:** Then, I tried to use `Any`:

```
var results =  await this.WorkobjectRepository.FindAllMatchingAsync(w => w.StatusDetailedDisplayName == StatusDetailedDisplay.activeOpen && caredTeams.Any(team => team.Id == w.AssignedSubteamId));
```

which failed, too:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Backend.DomainLayer.UserAccountSubteam'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

**Option 3:** Last, but not least I tried the following which failed too:

```
var results =  await this.WorkobjectRepository.FindAllMatchingAsync(w => w.StatusDetailedDisplayName == StatusDetailedDisplay.activeOpen && caredTeams.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(w.AssignedSubteamId));
```

Error message:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Backend.DomainLayer.UserAccountSubteam'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

How is the correct way to achieve this? And please note that I am not able to change the basic function `FindAllMatchingAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

First option with `Contains` is correct way but can be simplified.

```cs
var teams = caredTeams.Select(t => t.Id);

return await this.WorkobjectRepository
   .FindAllMatchingAsync(w => w.StatusDetailedDisplayName == StatusDetailedDisplay.activeOpen 
      && teams.Contains(w.AssignedSubteamId));
```

Comment: Why does none of the options I mentioned work ,i.e. `Exists`, `Any`...? Is there no way to use `Exists` or `Any` in this context?

Comment: Simple answer: because LINQ translator do not support other translations with client-side collections.